# Leitura e divisão de ficheiros em C

Tags: c

Estou a fazer um projeto para a faculdade, o código já lê os ficheiros e divide as linhas tendo em conta o ";", como posso gravar estes *tokens* em variáveis?

```
struct informacaoFicheiroInput{
    int id;
    int acompanhantes;
    char tipo[11];
    int entrada;
    int saida;
    int servico;
};

void lerFicheiroInput(){
    struct informacaoFicheiroInput informacao[20];

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("input.txt","r");

    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Não foi possivel abrir o arquivo.\n");
    }

    char line[20], *token, dados[11][20];

    while(fgets(line, 100, file) != NULL){
        int count = 0;
        token = strtok(line,";");

        while(token != NULL) {
            dados[count++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }
    }
}
```

O ficheiro input é do genero:

```
10 ; Visitante ; 10 ; 19 ; 2
2 ; 1 ; Funcionario ; 8 ; 0
3 ; 2 ; Diretor ; 12 ; 19
4 ; Visitante ; 8 ; 0 ; 3
```

Comment: Podes fazer `int inteiro = atoi(dados[x][y]);` para obter os inteiros, e `strcpy(string, dados[x][y]);` para copiar as strings. No ficheiro de entrada, faltaram os delimitadores no fim da linha, `10; Visitante; 10; 19; 2;<quebra>`

Comment: Vou experimentar, o que faz a função atoi? Não consigo mudar o ficheiro de entrada, como faço?

Comment: `int atoi(const char* s)` toma uma cadeia de caracteres como parâmetro, tenta convertê-la em inteiro, e devolve este valor inteiro.

Comment: Obrigado, fiquei esclarecido!

Comment: Talvez seja necessário incluir a quebra de linha como delimitador, no `strok`: `token = strtok(line, ";\n");`

Comment: Não consegui usar int inteiro = atoi(dados[x][y]); para obter os inteiros, e a strcpy(string, dados[x][y]), pode meter isso em codigo para ver se funciona?

Comment: O que cada elemento de uma linha do ficheiro significa?

Comment: Se o tipo de funcionario for funcionario ou diretor, a linha será deste genero 2 ; 1 ; Funcionario ; 8 ; 0, ou seja, por ordem, id, acompanhantes, tipo, horas de entrada, horas de saida
Se o tipo de funcionario for visitante, a linha será  do tipo 4 ; Visitante ; 8 ; 0 ; 3, ou seja, por ordem, id, tipo, horas de entrada, horas de entrada, e o numero do id do funcionario que vai visitar

Comment: Os espaços entre dados, mostrados no seu exemplo de ficheiro, estão lá, mesmo? Ou foram incluídos a título de legibilidade?

Comment: Os espaços antes e depois dos ";", tais como as quebras de linha no final de cada frase encontram-se lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
void lerFicheiroInput(){
    struct informacaoFicheiroInput informacao[4];

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("input.txt","r");

    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Não foi possivel abrir o arquivo.\n");
    }

    char line[100], *token, dados[5][20];
    int info = 0;

    while(fgets(line, 100, file) != NULL){
        int count = 0;
        token = strtok(line,";");

        while(token != NULL && count < 5) {
            dados[count++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }

        // Mete os dados lidos da info-esima linha
        // em informacao.
        if (strcmp(" Visitante ", dados[1]) == 0){
            informacao[info].id = atoi(dados[0]);
            strcpy(informacao[info].tipo, dados[1]);
            informacao[info].entrada = atoi(dados[2]);
            informacao[info].saida = atoi(dados[3]);
            informacao[info].servico = atoi(dados[4]);
        } else {
            informacao[info].id = atoi(dados[0]);
            informacao[info].acompanhantes = atoi(dados[1]);
            strcpy(informacao[info].tipo, dados[2]);
            informacao[info].entrada = atoi(dados[3]);
            informacao[info].saida = atoi(dados[4]);
        }
        ++info;
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Só tenho um problema, a linha dados[count++] = token; está me a dar erro, é o seguinte " assignment to expression with array type"

Comment: Troca a linha de `dados[count++] = token;` para `strcpy(dados[count++], token);`, por favor. Obrigado.

Comment: Inclui também `#include <string.h>` no topo do programa.

Comment: Assim já funciona bem! Muito obrigado

Comment: Favor marcar como resposta, caso o código seja-lhe útil.

Comment: Já está feito! Agradeço a ajuda